# esriJobMessageTypeError: ERROR 000816: The tool is not valid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service, error-000816

I am trying to publish a model from ModelBuilder so that I can use it on my GIS-Web application, so to start with I have created a model with parameters for buffer, and tested it on ArcMap (Desktop) and it works fine, but when I published it on server, and want to run it, an error appears :

> esriJobMessageTypeError: ERROR 000816: The tool is not valid.

I have attached some captures

[image: Model for buffer]

[image: Geoprecessing parameters]

[image: After publishing the service]

[image: buffer model from server]

[image: Results from server]

**Edit 1**

I have followed these instructions : 1) I have created a folder that contains a toolbox and two folders, one named scratch and the other ToolData, 2) I have added the shapefiles into scratch folder. 3) I created a file geodatabsae called Schema withing the Tooldata folder 4) I have added the shapefiles into the Schema gdb, 5) I have created the model inside the toolbox. 5) I ran the model and it works correctly but when I publish it, it stop working with the error that I mentioned, I think the problem is with the inputs, I don't know why , but when publishing the service, a message appears to confirm uploading the shapefiles and I accept so the process can be done

Comment: Do you have some objects selected from the input layer?  If you've got an object selected that has no geometry, I could see it spitting out that error.

Comment: @P.T.Curran please the the edited version

Comment: If you're doing all those steps, why not make them part of one model, rather than executing them separately?  You could be getting the data in your scratch workspace wiped out when going from one step to the next.

Comment: @RSSIG'IST, do the versions of ArcMap and Server match? Gp services are picky. Make sure you are using the same versions of ArcGIS Server as Desktop. That's actually a requirement for GP services.

If you're publishing a geoprocessing service, the ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server versions must match.

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/compatibility-of-arcgis-for-server-with-earlier-versions.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A2CA2669A53C4E36B39C5792A020A418

Answer (score 1):

I can say with almost absolute certainty that the problem is mis-matched versions of ArcMap and ArcGIS Server (as Don points out in the comments).

The buffer tool has been enhanced with new parameters/options between the versions. The buffer tool has had [changes at 10.1 and 10.3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/analysis-toolbox-history.htm). The publishing process cannot resolve differences in the tools from version to version. For example, if you had ArcMap 10.3 and published to Server 10.2, there is no ability for Server to magically add that new parameter (and Server can't simply ignore that parameter, your workflow may require it). Thus you get the invalid tool error.

With Pro, the analyzers have been enhanced to [stop this situation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/share-analysis/00256-server-version-value-tool-value-does-not-have-new-parameter.htm), and you can *probably* get away with mis-matched server/pro versions when publishing.

Comment: I have the same issue but my versions of Desktop and Server match (10.8)